# Google Search's Nature Towards Joomla's Adminstrator Folder (and sub-folders)?

Tags: security

The files which are contained in Joomla's Admin Folder (and sub-folder)! Do they get listed in Google Search results ? or do we need to unlist them somehow (manually)? What about the Admin login page ? How to keep it safe, i mean anyone access the admin page directly (`/adminstrator/index.php`) how to secure that?

P.S - i have some custom **PHP** files (**with JOOMLA CMS IMPORTED**) in the root directory, will they show up in google search? Kindly, enlight me on that as i am about to upload my localhost website, i don't want to mess with **GOOGLE** :)

Comment: You should have seen robots.txt which says to crawlers not to index the declared path in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. While `/administrator/index.php` may get indexed (unlikely unless there's a link to it somewhere) it has no content of value.
2. In theory no you don't have to `unlist` them
3. See 1.
4. There are lots of ways to secure `/administrator` including:

   1. Using `cPanel` or similar to protect the directory `/administrator` with a basic access authentication, or `realm`
   2. Use something like [AdminTools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/14087) from [Akeeba](https://www.akeebabackup.com) or any of the other well ranked extensions under [`Site Security`](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection) on the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/)
5. **The output** of your custom PHP files will get searched by *any search engine* that can find a link to them. Note I said *output*, unless your server is badly configured the actual `php` code will not be searchable by them.
6. Bonus question (for you), have you setup a [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and [Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) account for your website?

Comment: i have setup an analytics account! btw what's realm? and P.S - i was thinking about using .htaccess and .htpasswd for the administrator folder.will that be secure enough?

Comment: When you setup a password for a directory with .htaccess/.htpasswd you're creating a `realm`, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication. Generally we do other things, as a minimum when we build a site we use at least AdminTools Pro.

Answer (score 5):

If you implement Joomla default **robots.txt** (it's always installed by default), it defines directory exclusions for crawlers:

```
# If the Joomla site is installed within a folder such as at
# e.g. www.example.com/joomla/ the robots.txt file MUST be
# moved to the site root at e.g. www.example.com/robots.txt
# AND the joomla folder name MUST be prefixed to the disallowed
# path, e.g. the Disallow rule for the /administrator/ folder
# MUST be changed to read Disallow: /joomla/administrator/
#
# For more information about the robots.txt standard, see:
# http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html
#
# For syntax checking, see:
# http://tool.motoricerca.info/robots-checker.phtml

User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /bin/
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /layouts/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /tmp/
```

Reference: http://docs.joomla.org/Robots.txt